# JavaFX packaging - automatically set Windows Startup program

Tags: windows, netbeans, ant, javafx

I enabled Native Packaging for my JavaFX app and used a sample build.xml ant task script for deploying which allows to set app's version, title, vendor and so on.
 The question is, are there any attributes for an ant task or any other configurations that will allow to set app as a Windows start up program?
P.S. I'm using NetBeans IDE
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do it using JavaFX task script, but you can do it in your INNO script, which you are loading via ant.

Comment: Can you provide any links or documentation on that, because I'm not very good at ant/inno scripting?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is [Oracle's JavaFX ANT tasks documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html). Take a look at [section 10.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html#CHDBGIJG). It explains how to create self-contained applications (installables) using a `<fx:deploy>` ANT task.

Of course you'll need to either have Inno Setup or Wix installed in your machine in order to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no ANT task** to set the app as a Windows start-up program (at the best of my knowledge at least), but there are two types of [Inno Setup configuration](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startwithwindows) to do it as the followings:

1. Registry entry (works on almost all versions of Windows since WinXP):
   `[Registry]`
   `;current user only`
   `Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppName}"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks:AutoRunRegistry;`

   `;any user`
   `Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppName}"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks:AutoRunRegistry;`
2. Creating Shortcut (reported not working from Windows 8 as this SO Discussion claims, but I haven't tested it):
   `[Icons]`
   `Name: "{userstartup}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks:StartMenuEntry;`
   `Name: "{commonstartup}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks:StartMenuEntry;`

Here, `#MyAppName` & `#MyAppExeName` were declared with `#define`at the start of my configuration file.